# Constraints on K under Slepian decoding

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

1.What are the size constraints on k if we want C to be a ternary [50, k] code that is 1-error correcting under Slepian decoding?
This one I found k <= 50 - log_3 ((3-1)50+1)  = 50 - log_3 (101) which is about 45.... So k <= 45

2.What are the size constraints on k if we want C to be a ternary [50, k] code that is 2-error correcting under Slepian decoding

For the second one, how to do it?